# Firefox Crashing frequently

Tags: 16.04, firefox, ssd, ram, crash

I have a fresh Installation of Ubuntu 16.04. The firefox is crashing frequently(every 10-15 minutes) and showing this box.

[image]

[Here are the details of the report](https://pastebin.com/BQcrv3FN).

Could it be an issue related to **hardware**? I could not tell much from the details of the report but a few reasons why I am guessing Hardware are:

1. I recently changed the Motherboard, added an extra 4GB RAM and replaced HDD with SSD.
2. I have a dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04 and I am facing the same problem there(Ubuntu 20.04) too.
3. While running some other commands, I am frequently getting a **Segmentation Fault** error.

If the **hardware** is the culprit, **which component** could be the reason? If it is a software issue, what could be the solution?

**Update**: *MemTest* was completed. Here are the results for the same after completion of the Test.

It says ***one error found***. Could this be the reason for all the issues I am facing? Or is it normal to have 1 error?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check memory with `memtest`. It must be a hardware issue.

Comment: I agree with @Pilot6. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: Thank you, I have started the memtest. I will update the question with the results once it is complete.

Comment: Added the results of the memtest in the question. It says one error found. Could this be the reason for all the issues I am facing? Or is it normal to have 1 error?

Comment: In the crash dialog box, check "Tell Mozilla about this crash..." (other items are optional), "Details" might give some info. Then click on Restart Firefox. Then, in the url bar, enter about:crashes, and you should see an entry for that crash (it may take a few minutes), along with details about it. That would be helpful to enter in your question.

Comment: The issue was with RAM. The problem was caused by the addition of the RAM stick with different frequencies. The previous RAM's frequency was 1333 and the newer one had a frequency of 1600 MHz. Independently both are working fine but when used together the system is crashing at times. I tried changing DRAM Frequency in the BIOS but it didn't help. So, I got another single 8GB RAM which is working fine now.

Comment: Since the question has taken a different direction, please suggest how should I update the question so that it can be useful to others. Thank you.